# Display authenticated users on non-secure (anonymous) routes

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, twig, silex

I use PHP and Silex to build a web app and I implemented basic authentication via `SecurityServiceProvider` like this:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'private' => array(
            'remember_me' => array(
                'key' => $config['secret_key'],
                'lifetime' => $config['remember_me_duration'],
            ),
            'pattern' => '^/admin',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                // ...
            }),
        ),
        'public' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/$',
            'anonymous' => true,
        ),
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
            'anonymous' => true,
        ),
    ),
));
```

As you can see the `/admin` paths are secured, there I can use `$app['security']->getToken()->getUser();` to get the actual user that is authenticated and display something like *Logged in as $username*, but if I do this on the `/login` or `/` routes the user will always be `anon.` even if I'm authenticated.

How can I get the authenticated user, if there is one, otherwise the `anon.` string, on the `/` and `/login` routes in order to display a message like: *Logged in as $username* ?

I also tried to use `is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'` function in the twig templates to check if the user is authenticated, but on `/login` and `/` it returns false (even if I'm authenticated) since the anonymous user takes precedence over the authenticated ones, so no success here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything must be under the same firewall and you have to use access control.

Comment: Could you provide an example please? I'll (re)try to do it, but I used access_control before with no success.

Answer (score 6):

In order to help other people, I solved the issue as described below.
Silex doesn't use `access_control`, but `access_rules` (dammit).

As **Pazi** (+1ed) suggested I combined everything under a single firewall and used `access_rules`:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'remember_me' => array(
                'key' => $config['secret_key'],
                'lifetime' => $config['remember_me_duration'],
            ),
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/login',
                'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
            ),
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                // ...
            }),
        ),
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(array('^/admin/files', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paul
I'd prefer to add the comment but I can't do it yet, so as an answer than:

It looks like taking out

```
'pattern' => '^/admin'
```

string from the firewall pattern you have opened anonymous access to the /admin/login_check, and this is not right.

My suggestion is to take it back and remove

```
'anonymous' => 'true'
```

line from the firewall. Should work the same but would be more secured.